# How to get the page hostname in Angular 2?

Tags: angular2-routing

I need to get the subdomain of a page in Angular 2 because it is relevant to the route. I see that after multiple breaking releases the Router service in Angular 2 still has no notion of domain. Similarly, the Location service is ignorant of the host part of the URL.

Comment: btw. I know I can do window.location.host.split('.')[0] . I am just hoping there is a more fitting way of doing it in Angular2.

Answer (score 6):

There is no build in way to get current host.

If you don't want to use `window.location` directly you can inject it, i.e. if you need only host you can add the following into module providers:

```
{ provide: 'HOST', useValue: window.location.host }
```

then you can inject it in component or service:

```
constructor(@Inject('HOST') private host: string) { }
```

For sure you can provide whole `window` object:

```
{ provide: Window, useValue: window }
```

And then inject it:

```
constructor(private window: Window) { }
```

**UPDATE**

first option won't work on AOT builds, you should use a factory instead:

```
export function hostFactory() { return window.location.host; }
```

and then provider:

```
{ provide: 'HOSTNAME', useFactory: hostFactory }
```

Comment: Your updated solution is the best solution, because you can mock it in test.

Answer (score 2):

I got the hostname just using this: 
`window.location.hostname`

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be using Angular's [`DOCUMENT`](https://angular.io/api/common/DOCUMENT) injection token.

```js
// import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

constructor(
  @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document,
) {
  console.log(this.document.location.hostname);
}
```