# Angular 5: Get host name and app name from URL

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

My current url is:

https://localhost:8080/MyApp/manager/dashboard

Within the above url I want to fetch only https://localhost:8080/MyApp/ part.

Is there any way to fetch this without hard coding anything?

Comment: Is it a business rule ? If so, could you tell us what it is ?

Comment: @trichetriche, the requirement is to fetch the hostname and app name only from url.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864584/how-to-get-the-page-hostname-in-angular-2.

Answer (score 24):

**window.location** contains lots of information. Suppose the URL is
https://example.com:80/a/b/c, you can get following information easily in Angular:

```
window.location.hostname = "example.com"
window.location.host = "example.com:80"
window.location.protocol = "https:"
window.location.port = "80"
window.location.pathname = "/a/b/c"
window.location.href     = "https://example.com:80/a/b/c"
```

Answer (score 14):

If you want to get the domain name and application name only, rely on the router location and on the window location.

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private loc: Location) {}

ngOnInit() {
  const angularRoute = this.loc.path();
  const url = window.location.href;

  const domainAndApp = url.replace(angularRoute, '');
}
```

Comment: Ty @user467634. Suggestion: I would say that `const domainAndApp = url.replace(\`#${angularRoute}\`, '');` is more suitable :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get hostname and port name from the URL, then you can simply do the `console.log(location);`

This will return the separate value of each.

```
host: "localhost:4200",
hostname: "localhost",
href: "http://localhost:4200/order-form/2",
origin: "http://localhost:4200",
pathname: "/order-form/2",
port: "4200",
protocol: "http:",
```

in your case this should `console.log(location.origin);`